# Google Maps API Distance Mapping in Java

Tags: java, google-maps

So I have found the coordinates of two addresses using the API. I need to find out if they are within a given distance(lets say 10 miles) of each other. All examples I have found have been in JavaScript. Here is the outline of my method:

```
  public Boolean isClose(String[] loc1, String[] loc2){
            double x1 = Double.parseDouble(loc1[0]);
            double x2 = Double.parseDouble(loc2[0]);
            double y1 = Double.parseDouble(loc1[1]);
            double y2 = Double.parseDouble(loc2[1]);


        return true; //returns true if the two locations are in the distance specified above
    }
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Answer (score 1):

```
private static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

        return (dist);
    }
```

this is from another site, maybe it could help.